# Local vue.js dont fire ready function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The following code runs ok in jsfiddle, but in localhost appear the ready function doesnt fire and ol itens are not displayed. How solve this?

index.html

```
<body>
  <h3>Notícias</h3>
  <div id="app">
    <ol>
      <li v-for="noticia in noticias">
        <span>{{ noticia.id }}</span>
        <span>{{ noticia.titulo }}</span>
        <span>{{ noticia.data_inicio }}</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var noticias = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "titulo": "Lorem ipsum",
    "conteudo": "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet",
    "data_inicio": "1990-12-06",
    "data_fim": "1990-12-07",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "titulo": "Lorem ipsum sit",
    "conteudo": "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet",
    "data_inicio": "1998-12-06",
    "data_fim": "1998-12-10",
  }
];

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
      noticias: []
    },

    ready: function() {
      this.$set('noticias', noticias);
    },

});
```

The index.html and app.js are in the same directory.

Comment: Can you share fiddle link, and which version of Vue you are using locally.

Comment: If you are using VueJS 2, `ready()` lifecycle hook won't work because it's deprecated.Instead, you should go with `mounted()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ready()` is le passé, if you're on `2.x` use `mounted()` function instead.